# cakephp : multiple Group By conditions with query builder

Tags: cakephp, group-by, builder

I am trying to use multiple group by conditions in Cakephp.
With this doc as ref :

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html

I went on and used :

```
 $query = $events
  ->group('date');


foreach($query as $event):?> //beginning of my display results
```

this works, however, I need other parameters in my group condition, so that it does not only returns me one result per date. But filters and displays the different texts on a same date, just not multiple times the same text at the same date.

So I tried doing this :

```
 ->group('date', 'text');
```

But it does not work as I hoped :
it does both conditions separetely and therefore if I have two posts with a different text on the same date, it will only show me one.
Thanks for your time

Comment: try `->group(['date', 'text']);`

Comment: Thanks ! this works !