# I want to display product information by grouping them as one in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a **product** table with `id`, `product_name` and `added_date`.
I want to display `product_name` and `added_date` but I have the following condition to display the results

1. For `product_name` column: if multiple records with the same `product_name` are registered, the latest id value should be displayed.
2. For `added_date` column: multiple records with the same `added_date` are registered, the latest id value should be displayed.

I tried the following but it didnot gave result as exprected:

```
$products = $this->Products->find()
            ->group([
                'Products.product_name',
                'Products.added_date',
                ])
            ->order([
                'Product.added_date DESC',
                'Product.id DESC'
            ])
            ->all();
```

Comment: For a very specific queries, consider building a full query: https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/database-basics.html#running-select-statements

Comment: I'm not getting what exactly you need in your output. You can GROUP by two columns, but then you'll get multiple rows in your result. That's simple and I doubt that's what you want. See [cakephp array groupby multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54662482) or maybe even  [cakephp : multiple Group By conditions with query builder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44393618). Maybe a sample of your desired output would help us understand better?